# install Cirrus Logic cs46xx (audio card) drivers

Tags: drivers, soundcard

I have two sounds cards, one is the on-board (it's VIA) the other is Cirrus Logic cs46xx. This is what lspci shows me:
`04:04.0 Multimedia audio controller: Cirrus Logic CS 4614/22/24/30 [CrystalClear SoundFusion Audio Accelerator] (rev 01)` 
It only show the cirrus logic, cause I disable the VIA card through BIOS.

This page: http://es.driverscollection.com/?file_id=13152 gives me instructions to install it, but I can follow them because the folders indicates in the page do not matches with the ones that I see in my system.

The alsa page: http://alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Matrix:Module-cs46xx, also give me instructions, but I don't understand it. For example, they say: type in a terminal: `./configure` but don't say in what directory. I think that isn't instructions for begginers...

Right now I can't heard anything.

I decide to disable the VIA audio card, cause I've read they don't get along with linux, although i use the integrate VIA video card.

I have ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 4):

snd-cs46xx is a Linux kernel module supporting Cirrus Logic's Sound Fusion CS46xx audio controllers. It is an ALSA driver included in the Linux kernel.

At linux-2.6 2.6.23-1, the binary-only firmware in this driver was removed (see the package changelog), due to discovered firmware licensing issues. The driver was disabled at this time. Firmware was also removed from the alsa-source package to resolve bug 483918.

At linux-2.6 2.6.31-1~experimental.1, the snd-cs46xx driver was re-enabled and patched to use firmware from userspace (resolving Debian bug 464197).

Device firmware is unable to be distributed by the Debian project, as the snd-cs46xx driver has no license.1 A free redistribution license has been requested from Cirrus Logic.2

[This page](http://wiki.debian.org/snd-cs46xx) This page describes how to enable support for sound devices based on CS46xx chipsets on Debian systems.